# Unable to install the ipa into iPad

Tags: ipa

[image: HI i have created ipa file with distributed provisioning profile. i have installed in my iPad it was installed but my client location they tried to install the ipa file but iTunes show always installing and in iPad displayed error. error is **iTunes Sync 'app name' failed to install.** i have added all the device UDID's in developer account and generated distributed provisioning profile.from the last 3days onwards i am working on same issue please help me.]

HI i have created ipa file with distributed provisioning profile. i have installed in my iPad it was installed but my client location they tried to install the ipa file but iTunes show always installing and in iPad displayed error. error is **iTunes Sync 'app name' failed to install.**  i have added all the device UDID's in developer account and generated distributed provisioning profile.from the last 3days onwards i am working on same issue please help me i am sharing screen shot please refer and give a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did you install the `ProvisioningProfile` onto your iPad separately? (first)
- Did you compile your app with your `ProvisioningProfile`?

There are many reasons it could not be installing. You should double check each step, from downloading your `PP` to compiling, to installing your `PP` on your iPad, to installing your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i have not selected exact provisioning while generating ipa file. now it's working fine

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out. If my answer helped, can you accept it?

Comment: Please click the green checkbox to the left of my answer then please :) This makes people want to help you more (and increases your stackOverflow points)